# Landscape openstack juju management

Tags: juju, openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I have installed landscape openstack autopilot ([Build OpenStack with conjure-up | Download | Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack)).

Can somebody help me to understand how can I deploy services such as ceilometer?
I download juju configuration, then copy it to .juju/enviroments.yaml. After add username, password. Then from terminal use "juju bootstrap". When it's bootstraped I have new instance in my openstack dashboard.

After I want to deploy ceilometer ([ceilometer | Juju](https://jujucharms.com/u/yolanda.robla/ceilometer/precise/16))

But on adding relations to rabbitmq and keystone it failes saying "unable to connect to keystone". How can I connect keystone, which was installed during openstack installation with ceilometer or any other service?

Maybe I'm doing everything wrong? Juju has been already bootstrapped while installing openstack. How can I connect to it to deploy new services?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get access to the juju environment, please run the following from the place where you installed LDS:

```
# If you used the install-openstack tool, you want to do this first:
export JUJU_HOME=~/.cloud-install/juju
juju status

# Get an interactive shell with the right ENV sourced on the landscape
# server itself.
juju ssh landscape-server/0 sudo 'JUJU_HOME=/var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/`sudo ls -rt /var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/ | tail -1` sudo -u landscape -E bash'

# You should see a lot of openstack services with this command:
juju status
```

At this point, you can poke around, deploy services, and generally wreak havoc in your environment.

In other words, here is where you would deploy ceilometer.

Good Luck!

Comment: I have a problem with second command:


cmt@cmtUbuntu:~$ export JUJU_HOME=~/.cloud-install/
cmt@cmtUbuntu:~$ echo $JUJU_HOME
/home/cmt/.cloud-install/
cmt@cmtUbuntu:~$ juju status
ERROR Unable to connect to environment "".
Please check your credentials or use 'juju bootstrap' to create a new environment.

Error details:
no environment specified

Comment: I have in .cloud-install next files: charmconf.yaml, commands.log, config.yaml, landscape.yaml, timings.yaml. I don not have enviroment.yaml here. I have one in .cloud-install/juju/

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. everything works fine=) Ceilometer has been successfully deployed

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks to all of you=) I'm increasing my knowledge day by day=) ceilometer has been successfully deployed (have posted the way i've done this if you are interested): http://askubuntu.com/questions/598297/ceilometer-deployment

Comment: @dpb Hm.. I have one question.. Why ceilometer is deploying in landscape's region? not in openstack's? After installing and changing endpoint i have just notification metrics... But i need Pollster ones.. I've tryed to add samples. it has been added but nothing changed Any suggestions?

Comment: @KostyaBorisenko A pastebin with juju status showing ceilometer would be useful here.