# Ceilometer deployment

Tags: juju, openstack, cloud, openstack-autopilot

This is next question after making: [Landscape openstack juju management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597979/landscape-openstack-juju-management)

Now I'm trying to deploy ceilometer. doing this by juju deploy ceilometer (https://jujucharms.com/u/yolanda.robla/ceilometer/precise/16) made nothing changed to openstack dashboard. Actually there was one difference: i added relation not to rabbitmq but to rabbitmq-server, because i have none rabitmq.

After that i tried next: http://docs.openstack.org/havana/install-guide/install/apt/content/ceilometer-install.html
In this page it is said:  Before you can install these agents on nodes such as the compute node, you must use this procedure to install the core components on the controller node. I know I'm newbie in Openstack, but what is controller node?

Can somebody help me with juju deployment or with manual telemetry deployment?

Thank you for attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I have done ceilometer deployment.
After installing landscape openstack autopilot you need to do next things:

1. From host where you have executed openstack-install:

   ```
   # If you used the install-openstack tool, you want to do this first:
   export JUJU_HOME=~/.cloud-install/juju
   juju status

   # Get an interactive shell with the right ENV sourced on the landscape
   # server itself.
   juju ssh landscape/0 sudo 'JUJU_HOME=/var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/`sudo ls -rt /var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/ | tail -1` sudo -u landscape -E bash'

   # You should see a lot of openstack services with this command: 
   juju status
   ```
2. To deploy with juju i'm creating for service new container:

   ```
   juju deploy ceilometer --to lxc:0
   ```

   This will create new lxc container for ceilometer. For looking if ceilometer has started use:

   ```
   watch juju status ceilometer
   ```

   ok, you need need to execute next commands:

   ```
   juju deploy mongodb --to lxc/0
   juju add-relation ceilometer mongodb
   juju add-relation ceilometer rabbitmq-server
   juju add-relation ceilometer keystone
   juju deploy ceilometer-agent
   juju add-relation ceilometer-agent nova-compute
   juju add-relation ceilometer:ceilometer-service ceilometer-agent:ceilometer-service
   juju expose mongodb
   juju expose ceilometer
   juju expose ceilometer-agent
   ```

Wait until everything is started (juju status).

3. So after that ceilometer is installed. But in my case it has been installed to regionOne (landscape's), not in my region. So, I fix it in that way: 
   You need to connect to machine where you have installed ceilometer. You can find it using juju status ceilometer. My container is 0/lxc/10:

   ```
   juju ssh 0/lxc/10
   ```

To get proper enviroment for keystone and ceilometer download openstack rc file:
[image]

on ceilometer's container run next:

```
    sudo nano admin-openrc.sh
```

And copy text from downloaded file to new file. Save it and close.

4. Run next:

   ```
   source admin-openrc.sh
   #enter your openstack password (you can find it on your landscape monitor page)
   keystone endpoint-list
   #copy id of endpoint with uncorrect region. And remember the url.
   keystone endpoint-delete  **paste this ID**
   keystone endpoint-create --region **YOUR_REGION** --service-id ceilometer --publicurl="**CEILOMETER_URL**" --adminurl="**CEILOMETER_URL**" --internalurl="**CEILOMETER_URL**"
   ```

   5.Relogin to your dashboard. If you have made everything right you will see Resource Usage on your admin's panel and clicking "Generating report" won't go into mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You are on your own here, since you are changing the environment that autopilot deployed. If you want, you can try following the charm readme: https://api.jujucharms.com/v4/trusty/ceilometer-3/archive/README.md

But this is entirely unsupported.

The next version of Landscape will deploy ceilometer.

Comment: When using juju, you don't have to worry about nodes, just services. You need to deploy the ceilometer service, then relate it to the other services and so on.

Comment: But if I use just juju deploy ceilometer it wants to create new machine. But I do not have one, so I use juju deploy ceilometer --to 0 and it deploys to compute node, is this right? The only problem I have faced is that ceilometer is deploying on landscape's region, not on my region of openstack...