# error to deploy of openstack-autopilot on a single virtual machine via KVM

Tags: openstack-autopilot

After running all steps to install the Canonical Distribution on our virtual machine, using Ubuntu14.04.2Lts Svr Edition, I've received an error at the end of that, as we've reported in this post:

[error on the deploy of openstack-autopilot “failed status”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599162/error-on-the-deploy-of-openstack-autopilot-failed-status)

I've decided, as suggested us by dpb, to try to use the single machine option of `openstack-install` and testing openstack on our host. During the install I've not received any error, but it took 3h to run the installer and it continued to stay on "Creating Container:", as reported on this image:

[image]

then

[image]

it remains in this status for long time....

after 3hr the situation is invariable

[image]

any suggestions?

Comment: As we've asked before, please provide ~/.cloud-install/commands.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that screenshot is any indication of the Distro you're running (Utopic) there is a known bug with apparmor that causes the single installer to fail

https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/issues/470

The relevant launchpad bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/apparmor/+bug/1408833

You'll want to upgrade your kernel from that proposed pocket and report to our github bug if that fixes the installer issue.

Comment: in fact recently I've reported an error of Ubuntu 14.04.2 on virtual environment (Kvm), for that I've open a new question http://askubuntu.com/questions/601940/problem-to-run-ubuntu-14-04-2lts-on-virt-manager

Comment: Yes this problem is seen in 14.04.2, for the time being it is suggested to use 14.04.1