# How can I see what Openstack services have been deployed to which servers once Openstack Autopilot has completed successfully?

Tags: juju, openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I have successfully used the openstack-install on my MAAS server to install the Landscape managed option.

I have successfully configured the Openstack Autopilot beta options in the Landscape web console and run install.

I now have a clean Openstack deployment across my MAAS nodes (6).

I'd like to understand how Openstack services were distributed across my MAAS nodes by Autopoilot.

If on my MAAS server I type:

```
export JUJU_HOME=~/.cloud-install/juju
juju status
```

I can see how Landscape itself was deployed into lots of LXC containers on one of the MAAS nodes. What I can't see anywhere is how the Landscape Autopilot tool went on to use juju to deploy Openstack across the other nodes.

I really would like to understand what juju did in order to gain a better understanding of a) what I ended up with and b) how the Ubuntu Openstack reference deployment hangs together. How might I go about doing viewing the "juju status" of the Autopilot outcome?

Answer (score 6):

Similarly to:  [Landscape openstack juju management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597979/landscape-openstack-juju-management)

You can use the following:

```
# If you used the install-openstack tool, you want to do this first:
export JUJU_HOME=~/.cloud-install/juju
juju status

# Get an interactive shell with the right ENV sourced on the landscape
# server itself.
juju ssh landscape/0 sudo 'JUJU_HOME=/var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/`sudo ls -rt /var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/ | tail -1` sudo -u landscape -E bash'

# (or maybe this depending on your version of the tools)
juju ssh landscape-server/0 sudo 'JUJU_HOME=/var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/`sudo ls -rt /var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/ | tail -1` sudo -u landscape -E bash'

# You should see a lot of openstack services with this command:
juju status
```

Comment: Just so I understand the process, have I understood correctly that:  
- The command openstack-install run on the MAAS server offers me three install types for Openstack. I chose the Landscape Autopilot option.
- Having taken this option openstack-install then bootstraps juju to one of my MAAS nodes  
- Juju deploys Landscape to a MAAS node. That's the end of it for openstack-install.  
- Switching to the Landscape web console and doing the Openstack install initiates another series of juju deployments to fully configure an Openstack cloud. Is the same juju boostrap node used?

Comment: @AndrewLove Great summary -- you got it.  Once LDS has been installed, we bootstrap juju, but re-use the bootstrap node several times for openstack services so that no machines in your system are wasted.  So yes, the two environments are distinct.  Having a distinct environment/bootstrap for each related group of services is something of a best practice in the Juju world at this time.

Comment: OP can you mark this as the answer?