# Add node to existing landscape openstack

Tags: juju, openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

Does anyone have any resources, or know if it is possible to add a compute node to an existing landscape openstack configuration?

Or Do things like add services to a node ( like compute )

I don't mind getting dirty with the command line, I just didn't know the proper way to add to the openstack cluster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update March 7, 2017

Landscape now supports adding a storage/compute node to a running cloud.  You can do this through the UI after your cloud is deployed on the Openstack Dashboard.

### If you want to know what happens under the covers

Juju underneath supports expanding capacity of services and the nova compute charm also supports expanding capacity, that said, you could run into issues doing this, and it's entirely unsupported, dirty, messy and all that.  I would not recommend trying it if you are using the deployed cloud for anything live.

Similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606422/how-can-i-see-what-openstack-services-have-been-deployed-to-which-servers-once-o), you need to get access to the underlying openstack juju environment first.  After you do that:

```
# check that everything looks right, you should see a lot of openstack
# services displayed to your screen.
juju status 

# Expand compute capacity onto a named node
juju add-unit --to <name-in-maas>.<domain-in-maas> nova-compute

# Or Expand capacity to any free node in maas (note this will not
# check that capacity exists before running, you need to do that
# first)
juju add-unit nova-compute
```

When the autopilot supports doing this, things will be done in a different way as there are considerations I'm not going into (how to expand storage, how to expand admin services, how to monitor things, etc), but you going in and modifying the environment yourself is of course always an option.  It's your hardware, afterall.

BTW, I would recommend reading more on Juju and the way it models services.  This will be a good starting point:

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/charms

Comment: Thanks, I think I might just use charms / juju to set up the environment, however the landscape UI looks beautiful for the configuration

Comment: @EdwardBond Here are a few starting points for doing this yourself:   https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/OpenStackCharms/ReleaseNotes1504 , https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/clouddocs/en/Installing-OpenStack.html