# Openstack-autopilot and enabling the console

Tags: openstack, cloud, console, landscape, openstack-autopilot

By default the openstack cluster that comes up doesn't seem to have the console enabled. Trying to figure out what I might be doing wrong or what's up.

Is there any more detailed documentation around the environment other than:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack
?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't specific, an instance console, the nova.conf has: # cat /etc/nova/nova.conf | grep -i vnc
vnc_enabled = False
novnc_enabled = False

Comment: You can edit the original question...Stack Exchange works its own unique way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to access the underlying juju environment as described in your previous question: [Add node to existing landscape openstack](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621329/add-node-to-existing-landscape-openstack)

From there you'll want to run the following:

```
juju set nova-cloud-controller "console-access-protocol=novnc"
```

That'll enable the console via Horizon dashboard.