# How to add hardware to Openstack running with MAAS and Juju

Tags: hardware, juju, maas, openstack-autopilot

We have an Openstack cloud running on 7 servers, which was deployed with the Autopilot.  So 1 machine is the MAAS controller, one machine is for Landscape and Juju, and the other 5 are running the Openstack cloud.

We now want to add additional servers to serve as compute resources for the cloud, we assume Juju calls those nova-compute.

After registering the servers with MAAS, what do we need to do for our Openstack cloud to see these additional compute resources?

Answer (score 1):

please see the following answer, I believe it's exactly what you are looking for:

[Add node to existing landscape openstack](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621329/add-node-to-existing-landscape-openstack)

Comment: Alright, we will try what they are suggesting and update this question with whether or not it completely broke our cloud.