# Enabling Load Balancer as a Service (LBaaS) on Autopilot deployed OpenStack

Tags: openstack, cloud, openstack-autopilot

I have setup an OpenStack deployment in our office consisting of 10 nodes total.  We deployed using Autopilot, and everything is working great.

Our issue now is that I want to enable LBaaS support in OpenStack.  I have found several pages that discuss the commands that need to be executed in order to enable it, but none of these pages specifically cover an Autopilot deployed cluster.

How do I access the appropriate servers to enable the LBaaS support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer describes how to access the inner juju environment:

[Add node to existing landscape openstack](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621329/add-node-to-existing-landscape-openstack)

Ideally you should find a juju way to enable LBaaS, because that's how the cloud was deployed by the Autopilot.