# Autopilot - OpenStack - Reboot of cloud fails

Tags: cloud, openstack-autopilot

Is there a proper way to reboot the openstack cloud launched with Autopilot? I just had to do a hard reboot of some of my servers, and the cloud has stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this writing, there is no more graceful way to do this.  If services have stopped, [get access to your environment](https://askubuntu.com/a/606551/7056) then clean up the services manually -- usually by doing `juju resolved --retry <unit>` on everything that has failed.