# Ubuntu Openstack Installer

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, openstack-autopilot

I've successfully set up a MAAS/Juju environment and used the Landscape Autopilot installer to install Openstack on my cluster. However I'd like to be able to modify the existing cloud setup by deploying a couple more Juju charms. How do I accomplish this? I can't seem to SSH into the Juju bootstrap node:

$ ssh VMNode1.maas

Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'vmnode1.maas' differs from the key for the IP address '10.1.1.151'

Offending key for IP in /home/XXX/.ssh/known_hosts:18

Matching host key in /home/XXX/.ssh/known_hosts:19

Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes

Permission denied (publickey).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get access to the underlying environment through Juju.  The following Q/A gives the details on how to do this:

- [How can I see what Openstack services have been deployed to which servers once Openstack Autopilot has completed successfully?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606422/)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. However I'm wondering how to get sudo status on the landscape machine? I'm trying to scp across some files for a test charm, but I'm getting the good ol' Permission Denied.

Comment: Hey there -- 'landscape' user doesn't have sudo access.  Instead ssh initially as the 'ubuntu' user to become root.

Comment: Thanks, I asked a separate question for this and was answered: http://askubuntu.com/questions/824773/dont-have-sudo-privileges-in-juju-nodes-when-using-landscape