# Don't have sudo privileges in juju nodes when using Landscape

Tags: juju, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I'm working on a custom charm that I'd like to deploy in my Landscape setup. I've got a functional cloud up and running via MAAS and openstack-install (can launch instances etc). To get access to the juju setup used by Landscape, I did the following on my MAAS node:

*export JUJU_HOME=~/.cloud-install/juju

juju status

juju ssh landscape-server/0 sudo 'JUJU_HOME=/var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/sudo ls -rt /var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/ | tail -1 sudo -u landscape -E bash'

juju status*

(As per [How can I see what Openstack services have been deployed to which servers once Openstack Autopilot has completed successfully?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606422/how-can-i-see-what-openstack-services-have-been-deployed-to-which-servers-once-o))

So now I can SSH into the landscape node. However once I SSH in, I want to scp across the files for my custom charm so that I can deploy locally, but I get a Permission Denied error.

I can't even create a new directory as a regular user.
landscape@juju-machine-0-lxc-1:~$ mkdir ola
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘ola’: Permission denied

Sudo'ing asks for the landscape password, which I don't have. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can juju ssh into landscape-server/0 without the long sudo line, that will get you into that node as "ubuntu" which can sudo to any other user without a password, including landscape.

Put the files where you want in landscape-server/0, make sure the landscape user can access them, then become the landscape user and set JUJU_HOME. Then you can juju scp them into any node in the inner cloud environment.

The landscape user doesn't have a shell by default, that's why that long sudo line you found runs the bash command in the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using conjure-up I used that:

```
$:juju ssh landscape-server/0 sudo 'JUJU_DATA=/var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/`sudo ls -rt /var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/ | tail -1` sudo -u root -E bash'
```

Then switch to the non default controller with, here it is called controller:

```
$: juju switch controller
$: juju status
```