# Landscape stuck at 99% installation of openstack autopilot

Tags: openstack, landscape

I got openstack autopilot up & running by `sudo openstack-install` command. It ran installer & after juju bootstapping, downloaded & installed Landscape. In Landscape gui after selecting openstack services it began to deploying nodes and making lxcs & these kinda stuff. All different services got an "succeeded" badge & it seemed that everything was ok & untill it reach to 99% and stuck there at "Wait for SimpleStreams to sync an image." with "in progress" badge.

[Picture of SimpleStreams stuck at 99](http://q00i.imgup.net/stuckk99befd.JPG)

I am in dire need of getting this openstack over with.
Please someone help me out, it would be very appreciated

Comment: It will take debugging, could be any number of things stuck, from network processes to disk full conditions, etc.  Please check this answer for details on how to access the inner juju environment, and start looking around: http://askubuntu.com/questions/606422/how-can-i-see-what-openstack-services-have-been-deployed-to-which-servers-once-o.  If you can update your answer after it will help.

Comment: If this environment is still up, use the question/answer above to get into the glance-simplestreams-sync/0 unit (if I remember the name correctly) and look for its logs in /var/log/. It should tell you what is going on. That's the service that downloads the images that Landscape is waiting for.

Comment: @dpb I'm not sure it's gonna be possible to access to inner environment since the deploying services (at least on one of nodes) has not finished yet, but I will try it as soon as I go to uni lab. Other thing I'm seeking advice to is that 2 nodes for Maas & Landscape aside there're 3 remaining nodes each with 4 Gb of RAM. On one of them that is named "machine-0" by Landscape (under computers tab) load gets so high that after a while I can't even be able to ssh to quite around the time that the progress bar has reached to 97%. Could the lack of sufficient RAM be the issue?

Comment: @andreas No I canceled & removed the region, but I'll go for it hopefully next time I run into the error :))

Comment: 4G should be enough for a basic deployment, but it might not meet your expectations, it's certainly at the very bottom of the minimum suggested configuration.  You should be able to access the inner juju environment anytime after the 'bootstrap' step (the first one that took a long time) finishes.

Comment: I'll definitely give you a feedback once I try it again, tnx for instructions by the way

Comment: Hi, first I must thank you for all great instructions. Again I got stuck to 99% installing progress so I get into inner juju environment as you said to look for `glance-simplestreams-sync/0` to get any clue about what was going on & it read `current: maintenance` for `workload-status` field so helpless I just wait & wait (I guess it went for 2 & a half hours) till the page with openstack Dashboard button on appeared. Now it shows `active` for that field. but every thing seems a little slow. the browser takes around 30 seconds until it get to Dashboard, is it ok?

Comment: I have another question (a rather stupid one) I wanna throw here, now that openstack is up & running on 5 nodes (one for maas, one for LDS & three for services) how should I go if I wanna just simply shutdown the whole system that I'll be able to bring them up again with no damage to whole deployment of openstack? (I mean it's not possible to leave them on through all night unattended, you know)