# Can't access Openstack VM's after deploying the cloud via Autopilot and Landscape

Tags: ssh, openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I have successfully deployed the OpenStack cloud using Landscape, but now I need to ssh into VM running openstack-dashboard, and I can't.

I know the IP of that particular VM but it doesn't let me in via SSH and says my public key is invalid.

How can I log into that VM and others running OpenStack cloud components such as Glance, Keystone and Nova if I need to adjust settings and restart things via CLI?

Comment: What's the precise error message?

Answer (score 7):

Please read the following question:

[Landscape's Ubuntu OpenStack Autopilot: troubleshooting help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/610922)

It should be exactly what you need to start troubleshooting/exploring your environment.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Because I've done the openstack-install from my MAAS machine, I had to ssh to it and then follow these steps:

```
# If you used the install-openstack tool, you want to do this first:
export JUJU_HOME=~/.cloud-install/juju
juju status

# Get an interactive shell with the right ENV sourced on the landscape
# server itself.
juju ssh landscape/0 sudo 'JUJU_HOME=/var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/`sudo ls -rt /var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/ | tail -1` sudo -u landscape -E bash'

# You should see a lot of openstack services with this command:
juju status
```