# Landscape installation takes a long time

Tags: software-installation, openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I'm installing Landscape with the Landscape OpenStack Autopilot:

- Bootstrapping Juju took 233 sec
- Preparing Landscape: 10 sec
- Deploying Landscape has so far used 2620 sec (43 minutes, 40 seconds).

This is a very long time. Is it normal?

---

It just got to 3000 and gave an error:

From installer log:

```
File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/multi_install.py", line 771, in run_deployer
    raise Exception("Error deploying Landscape.")
Exception: Error deploying Landscape. )
```

A bit from the log :

```
  Service 'rabbitmq-server' does not need any more units added.\n2015-05-21 13:39:58 [DEBUG] deployer.import: Waiting for units before adding relations\n2015-05-21 13:43:32 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/0 change:pending\n2015-05-21 13:43:52 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/1 change:pending\n2015-05-21 13:44:12 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/2 change:pending\n2015-05-21 13:44:32 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/3 change:pending\n2015-05-21 13:44:52 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/4 change:pending\n2015-05-21 13:45:12 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/5 change:pending\n2015-05-21 14:29:30 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Connecting to environment...\n2015-05-21 14:29:32 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Connected to environment\n2015-05-21 14:29:32 [ERROR] deployer.import: Reached deployment timeout.. exiting\n2015-05-21 14:29:32 [INFO] deployer.cli: Deployment stopped. run time: 3015.07\n", 'status': 1}
[DEBUG â¢ 05-21 14:29:32] â¢ cloudinstall.utils â¢ (utils.py, global_exchandler, 63)]
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/utils.py", line 78, in run
    super().run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/machinewait.py", line 127, in do_continue
    self.installer.do_install()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/multi_install.py", line 177, in do_install
    self.loop).run()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/multi_install.py", line 708, in run
    self.deploy_landscape()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/multi_install.py", line 731, in deploy_landscape
    self.run_deployer()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/multi_install.py", line 771, in run_deployer
    raise Exception("Error deploying Landscape.")
Exception: Error deploying Landscape.
```

Comment: Maybe the services didn't come up? looks like deployer timed out before all the services started. In any case, check out these troubleshooting tips: http://askubuntu.com/questions/610922/landscapes-ubuntu-openstack-autopilot-troubleshooting-help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the MAAS nodes never left the "pending" state. Can you select a node in MAAS and click "start", and see if it reaches the "Deployed" state?

I suggest to configure juju to use MAAS (https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/config-maas) and then try to bootstrap and deploy the simple ubuntu charm to all nodes. This is a good pre-flight check.

Once you have the `~/.juju/environments.yaml` file configured as per instructions from the link above, it's a simple matter of:

```
juju bootstrap
juju deploy ubuntu -n N
```

Where `N` is the number of nodes you have in MAAS minus 1 (which was used for bootstrapping).

Comment: I can see one node in MAAS that has been deployed during the installation: svvu15maasctrl01.sky.v.no  Deployed admin.

Comment: Thanks for you answer - it looks like, at first, my MAAS does not work properly. With deploying nodes, it works ok first time (submission and deploy) but when JUJU want to use MAAS I get a lot of error messages in the MAAS log - and I may relate them to the servers running on Vmware.(yes,libvirt is installed and power controll is working)  I think I should try now to install MAAS an JUJU at Bare Metal.

Comment: MAAS works just fine with VMs, both for nodes and itself. I use it all the time in this way and it's great for testing. Usually the initial difficulties are around networking.