# Landspace Openstack Installation Hang at 91%

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I tried several times and each time, the Openstack installation stops at 91%.  How can I debug where and why it's stopping?

```
In progress Add unit to 'ntpmaster' service on 'surprised-mountain.maas'    Today 17:33 UTC
In progress Add unit to 'rabbitmq-server' service on 'disastrous-copper.maas'   Today 17:33 UTC
In progress Add unit to 'neutron-api' service on 'disastrous-copper.maas'   Today 17:33 UTC
In progress Add unit to 'mysql' service on 'surprised-mountain.maas'    Today 17:33 UTC
In progress Add unit to 'glance' service on 'worrisome-sister.maas' Today 17:33 UTC
```

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue. It is stuck at 83% on me

Answer (score 2):

It could be several things indeed. So let's go through the generic steps of getting logs from a failed deployment. First let's show how to get access to the different juju environments in play here:

- Landscape environment: where the Autopilot was deployed
- Autopilot environment: the cloud environment created by Autopilot

Taken from [Landscape openstack juju management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597979/landscape-openstack-juju-management):

To get access to the Landscape juju environment, please run the following from the place where you installed LDS:

```
# First we need to get to the Landscape juju environment.
# If you used the install-openstack tool, you want to do this first:
export JUJU_HOME=~/.cloud-install/juju
juju status


# Get an interactive shell with the right ENV sourced on the landscape
# server itself. This gives you access to the Autopilot deployed cloud
# juju environment:
juju ssh landscape/0 sudo 'JUJU_HOME=/var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/`sudo ls -rt /var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/ | tail -1` sudo -u landscape -E bash'

# You should see a lot of openstack services with this command:
juju status
```

At this point, you can poke around the cloud environment. To reach the unit `nova-compute/0`, for example, run `juju ssh nova-compute/0`.

The data and logs that are useful to debug a stalled deployment are as follows:

- `/var/log/landscape-server/*.log` from the `landscape/0` unit from the Landscape environment. In particular, `job-handler.log`.
- `/var/log/juju/*.log` from the cloud environment bootstrap unit (machine 0, run `juju ssh 0` to reach it from `landscape/0`)
- `juju status` output from the cloud environment
- how many computers, if any, you have registered in Landscape at the point you decided it stalled. If it's zero, then we need `/var/log/landscape/*.log` from any cloud environment unit, like `nova-compute/0`.

Answer (score 1):

This [launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/landscape/+bug/1446870) is the same issue, seems better to handle it there probably?

Comment: It is not a valid link anymore