# How to add a network to a node in openstack autopilot

Tags: maas, openstack, openstack-autopilot

I have an Openstack autopilot instance up and working. 
I would like to add a new network to a connection to one of the existing network nodes via adding a new cat 6 cable to another interface on a non network node.

My high level understanding would be something like:

1. Wire cable to host
2. access juju system
3. Assign "network role" to host from #1 ( I don't know how I would do that )
4. Configure new network on host with openvswitch
5. Create another external net to openstack

I used MAAS to configure these, I am not sure if I would have to use landscape or MaaS to specify the new networks or not.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "I would like to add a new network to a connection to one of the existing network nodes".

You can access the inner juju environment directly, and then use juju to add nodes, outside of autopilot. It's not supported, but should work for compute and storage nodes. Not sure about the rest, really depends on what you want to do.

To access the inner environment, follow the instructions from [Landscape openstack juju management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597979/landscape-openstack-juju-management)

Comment: What I mean by another network node, would be to add another network interface ( If I had 10.10.10.0/24, and wanted to add 10.10.11.0/24 ) how would I do that is what I am asking

Comment: There is nothing in Autopilot to handle that after the deployment is done. Either you deploy again, or you access the inner environment and do things manually, but that requires OpenStack and juju charms expertise.

Comment: Should I re tag/rephrase the question to know how to do that?