# openstack-autopilot - Additional services

Tags: juju, openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I have successfully installed openstack with Autopilot.
And now I would like to enable VPNaaS, I find guides around how to do that, but just wondering if its safe for me to start configuring the cloud services manually, or is there a correct way of doing this when deployed with Landscape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenStack Autopilot has no way to account for these additional unmanaged services. The safest way for you to proceed would be to use the Juju environment backing the Autopilot to deploy them. You would have to take responsibility to manage and maintain the extra services yourself as the Autopilot will not.

Comment: How would I access the Juju gui? Or do I only have access to the commandline?

Comment: I believe the GUI is not installed, but you have access to the CLI endpoint in your cloud's configuration details on Autopilot.

Comment: In Landscape under the Juju tab, I find that a Juju Environment is registered with an endpoint ip, if I ssh to that Node, and try to run a Juju command, it says juju is not installed, please install juju-core... I see Juju is installed on the MaaS server, but I dont find all the services listed there, so Im guessing thats not the right place...

Comment: Nevermind, found the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/597979/landscape-openstack-juju-management