# Landscape Openstack Autopilot Trying to Deploy Juju Gui internal environment

Tags: juju, openstack, landscape

Followed the direction of the link below

[Landscape openstack juju management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597979/landscape-openstack-juju-management)

$juju ssh landscape-server/0 sudo 'JUJU_HOME=/var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/`sudo ls -rt /var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/ | tail -1` sudo -u landscape -E bash'

When I am trying to deploy juju gui in internal environment.

landscape@juju-machine-0-lxc-1:~$ juju deploy --to 0 juju-gui
Getting this Error
"ERROR cannot load cookies: file locked for too long; giving up"

Please let me know how can i resolve it

Comment: I have never seen that error. Do other juju commands work, like `juju status --format=tabular`?

Comment: when i run juju status , It is showing me all the machines and services.

Comment: I meant juju status in the inner environment, after the big juju ssh landscape-server/0 command.

Comment: This is bug in juju version 1.25.3. Here is the link about the bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1534643

Comment: Thank you very much andreas. Can you please let me know how can i bypass this bug ?

Comment: You can install any *released* version of juju 1.25.x you want on the landscape-server/0 unit before starting the cloud deployment.

Comment: when i check internal environment it showing me 1.25.3,  How can i upgrade internal environment ? external environment is 1.25.4.

Comment: You can upgrade juju-core on the landscape-server units. Autopilot will use whatever juju-core is installed on those units by the time a cloud deploy is started. You just cannot use proposed or devel versions of juju-core, because those require different bootstrap settings.

Comment: Can you please let me  know how can I upgrade juju-core on the landscape-server ?