# OpenStack Autopilot Install - Change OVS settings?

Tags: networking, juju, openstack

Where can I change the settings for Neutron on an Autopilot install of OpenStack?

On my controller under /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini, I see:

```
###############################################################################
# [ WARNING ]
# Configuration file maintained by Juju. Local changes may be overwritten.
###############################################################################
```

I wish to change these settings so I can use the vlans I need on the external network, but I'm unsure how to change this with juju.

If this isn't possible, how best can I hook my external interface on my network role nodes to a VLAN on the physical switch they are connected to?

The entirety of the file looks like the below, and I need to access VLAN 3000, but I currently can't go above 2000 based on the config.

```
###############################################################################
# [ WARNING ]
# Configuration file maintained by Juju. Local changes may be overwritten.
###############################################################################
[ml2]
type_drivers = gre,vxlan,vlan,flat
tenant_network_types = gre,vxlan,vlan,flat
mechanism_drivers = openvswitch,hyperv,l2population

[ml2_type_gre]
tunnel_id_ranges = 1:1000

[ml2_type_vxlan]
vni_ranges = 1001:2000

[ml2_type_vlan]
network_vlan_ranges = physnet1:1000:2000

[ml2_type_flat]
flat_networks = 

[ovs]
enable_tunneling = True
local_ip = 10.96.96.102
bridge_mappings = physnet1:br-data

[agent]
tunnel_types = gre
l2_population = False
enable_distributed_routing = False


[securitygroup]
firewall_driver = neutron.agent.linux.iptables_firewall.OVSHybridIptablesFirewallDriver
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with the Autopilot directly. What you can do is change these settings after Autopilot deployed your cloud, but you will have to use juju.

First, access the inner cloud environment as explained here: [Landscape openstack juju management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597979/landscape-openstack-juju-management)

Then do a series of `juju get` commands against the services you want to change. In your case, it's going to be a set of `neutron-api`, `neutron-openvswitch` and `neutron-gateway`. Finally, use `juju set <service> key=value` to change the setting you want.

Be careful, of course :)